# Asking a question on teaching engineers mathematical thinking skills

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

A few months ago, I asked a question on [teaching engineers mathematical thinking skills](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634690/teaching-engineers-mathematical-thinking-skills) over at MSE. I also asked it a little later at [The Mathematics Teaching Community](https://mathematicsteachingcommunity.math.uga.edu/index.php/918/mathematical-thinking-skills-for-engineers), but traffic on that site is very low. Now that we have MESE, I suspect it would fit well here, but I hesitate to post the question on a third site. How does the community feel about posting the question here?

Answer (score 7):

I think it is fine. Just link to the previous questions, and perhaps summarize what answers you've gotten.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for asking. Generally speaking, I think significantly delayed cross-posts are not a problem (and in any case we should not be very strict as this stage of the development of the site). I would consider it as good form to acknowledge the pre-existing questions in some way, either by just linking them or perhaps preferably by incorporating what was already learned from earlier answers in OP (if this is feasible).